# C++ calling elements of a class within a struct

Tags: c++, class, object, struct, linked-list

In C++, I am trying to learn how to implement a linked list. I have a class that defines a color, and would like to reference specific elements of that class within my node struct. Is the following syntax correct?

```
//Create a class for colors
class Color
{
public:
    int red;
    int green;
    int blue;
    int alpha;
};

//Create an object to reference the color class
Color colorObject;


//Create a node struct
struct Node
{
    Color colorObject.red;
    Color colorObject.green;
    Color colorObject.blue;
    Color colorObject.alpha;

    Node *next;
};
```

Comment: No, it doesn't compile. It's unclear what you mean by "correct" if it doesn't compile.

Comment: `struct Node...` does not "create" anything - it just defines it. You need to actually *instantiate* it within a function somewhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to adapt your code to match your intent is to make the following change:

```
struct Node
{
    Color data;
    Node *next;
};
```

Now say you have an instance of a `Node` called `the_node` and you would like to access the elements of the `Color` data contained within that then you would do something like this:

```
std::cout << the_node.data.red;
```

This will prints the value of the red member in `Color` that's stored in the `data` member of `Node`. In case you want to search this up but didn't know the name of those `.`s there, search for "c++ member access operator".

Note that our linked list implementation here will only work with data that's of type `Color`, if you want to make a more general linked list class that can use any type for the data then you will need to use a template, have a look at the [answer from AlexanderVX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27221359/296460) for details on that.

Answer (score 5):

```
template <typename T>
struct Node
{
    T payload;
    Node *next;
};

Node<Color> oneColorNode;
oneColorNode.payload.red = 0xff;
```

Using templates we are able to parameterize the generic Node class with any type of payload like your example.

Comment: This answer is probably not what the poster is looking for, as the OP is clearly new to C++. This sort of answer is probably just going to cause confusion.

Comment: @cmbasnett The answer could be improved by an explanation, sure, but it's a valid answer nonetheless.

Comment: @cmbasnett Certainly, unless more explanation is given.

Comment: cmbasnett: *and would like to reference specific elements of that class within my node struct* - to me the question asked in a manner pointing to authors readiness to absorb that concept (or the person is probably aware of that but unsure whether to use it here or not).

Comment: @AlexanderVX Explain that in your post (and maybe consider a compilable example) please!